# UIScrollBar is adding a vertical offset when scrolled manually

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiwebview

I've a weird behaviour problem:

I've a WebView inside of a ScrollView. The WebView's is declared as follows:

```
let webView = UIWebView(frame:CGRectMake(x,0,self.bounds.width,webPageScroller!.frame.height))
```

where x is given by the caller. Now, you'd think that would put my WebView on the left corner but no, there's a fixed vertical offset which I can't get rid of.

Now, I also scroll programatically by calling:

```
webScroller.setContentOffset(offset, animated: true)
```

where offset is CGPointZero and the separation disappears. It comes back as soon as I scroll horizontally, however.

This is driving me nuts. Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, I just had to go in Interface Builder and untick "Adjust scroll view inset".